# capistrano-resque: Multistage with Different :workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, resque

I have two production AWS instances which will be running resque but listening for different queues.  Here is an example of my current configuration:

config/deploy/production/prod_resque_1.rb

```
server "<ip>", :web, :app, :resque_worker, :db, primary: true

set :resque_log_file, "log/resque.log"
set :resque_environment_task, true

set :workers, {
  "queue1" => 5,
  "*" => 2
}

after "deploy:restart", "resque:restart"
```

config/deploy/production/prod_resque_2.rb

```
server "<ip>", :web, :app, :resque_worker, :db, primary: true

set :resque_log_file, "log/resque.log"
set :resque_environment_task, true

set :workers, {
  "queue2,queue3,queue4" => 5
}

after "deploy:restart", "resque:restart"
```

Then, I have a "global" recipe:

```
load 'config/deploy/production/common'
load 'config/deploy/production/prod_resque_1'
load 'config/deploy/production/prod_resque_2'
```

The obvious problem is, when I call `cap prod_resque resque:start`, the `:workers` definition in `prod_resque_1` is overwritten by the load of `prod_resque_2`, resulting in both `prod_resque_1` and `prod_resque_2` both having workers listening to `queue2`, `queue3`, and `queue4` only.

My work around has been to run `cap prod_resque_1 resque:start` then `cap prod_resque_2 resque:start`, but this kind of defeats the purpose of capistrano.

Any suggestions for a cleaner solution allowing me to run `cap prod_resque resque:start` and have the "first" server running 7 workers, 5 listening to `queue1` and 2 listening to all queues, and the "second" server running 5 workers, only listening to `queue2`, `queue3`, and `queue4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of this is given in the capistrano-resque [docs](https://github.com/sshingler/capistrano-resque/blob/master/README.md): if you assign a different role to each server (or groups of servers), then you can define workers on a per role basis.

In your case you would do something like

```
role :queue_one_workers, [ip_from_prod_resque_1]
role :other_queue_workers, [ip_from_prod_resque_2]

set :workers, {
  :queue_one_workers   => {"queue1" => 5, "*" => 2},
  :other_queue_workers => {"queue2" => 5, "queue3" => 5, "queue4" => 5}
}
```